# d3js Create legend for bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, legend

I'm having a couple of issues with my bar chart. The current issue is trying to create a legend. The legend should read *Global* and *Local* (blue & green).
Currently the legend generates 5 boxes - 2 of them are colored. I assume it's going through my dataset and generating boxes for each set of columns. I do not want this.

After I get the legend formatted, I want to be able to have it interactive. So if they only want to see *global*, then they unselect *local*, and the chart updates dynamically. I know I'll need to adjust it and create a function to update data, domain, etc.

But before beginning down that road, I want to get the legend populating properly. But I would appreciate if the legend solution would lead down this road.

[**I have a working Fiddle you can play around with**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/juY5E/6/).

Data Sources

```
var colors =    {0: ["Local", "#377EB8"],
             1: ["Global", "#4DAF4A"]};

var dataset = [
            {"keyword": "payday loans", "global": 1400000, "local": 673000, "cpc": "14.11"},
            {"keyword": "title loans", "global": 165000, "local": 160000, "cpc": "12.53" },
            {"keyword": "personal loans", "global": 550000, "local": 301000, "cpc": "6.14"},
            {"keyword": "online personal loans", "global": 15400, "local": 12900, "cpc": "5.84"},
            {"keyword": "online title loans", "global": 111600, "local": 11500, "cpc": "11.74"}
        ];
```

Label Code

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    //.attr("x", w - 65)
    //.attr("y", 50)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,50)');


legend.selectAll('rect')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", w - 65)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
    })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        var color = colors[dataset.indexOf(d)][1];
        return color;
    });

legend.selectAll('text')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", w - 52)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 20 + 9;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        var text = colors[dataset.indexOf(d)][0];
        return text;
    });
```

I know my *Colors* array/object probably isn't the most efficient way. So I'm open to adjusting that if it helps with the solution.
Also, I would prefer that it is a Horizontal list instead of vertical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `colors` rather than `dataset` as parameter for the `.data()` of your legend.
In order for that to work, `colors` has to be an array rather than an object:

```
var colors = [ ["Local", "#377EB8"],
               ["Global", "#4DAF4A"] ];
```

The code for creating the legend then becomes:

```
var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(colors);

legendRect.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", w - 65)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10);

legendRect
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d[1];
    });

var legendText = legend.selectAll('text').data(colors);

legendText.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", w - 52);

legendText
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 20 + 9;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d[0];
    });
```

Cf [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juY5E/7/).

Comment: Nice.
And how would I make it horizontal?

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/juY5E/9/) I think rotated text is a little awkward to read though...

Comment: Also, if you want to do dynamic updates, you should learn about the [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)!

Comment: HAha. You're right. Rotated text like that is hard to read. And that's not what I wanted to accomplish. I'm thinking so they are side by side. *Global *Local (where the * would represent the box/color).  Right now they are stacked on top of each other. I'd rather have them next to each other.

Comment: [There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/juY5E/10/). But then this only works if your labels are short enough, so in a more general case, I still think a vertical legend is preferable.